# Problems with `npm -g install ajv` on github action runner

Tags: github-actions, npm-install

On a github action runner, I run `npm -g install ajv` successfully, but then the `ajv` command cannot be found.

This is the github action (simplified for this question):

```
name: Install ajv
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  install-ajv:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.5.1

      - name: Install ajv
        run: |
          set -x
          npm -g --no-fund install ajv
          which ajv
```

This is the result:

[image]

The install seems to work, but any attempt to use or access the (globally) installed `ajv` fails.

I've tried `sudo` and various other tricks, no luck. This should be working, and it's not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `ajv` package doesn't seem to provide an executable:

```
jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  $  npm install ajv -g                                               14:25:53

added 6 packages, and audited 7 packages in 469ms

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  $  ajv                                                              14:25:56
Command 'ajv' not found, did you mean:
  command 'aj5' from deb aspectj (1.9.2-2)
  command 'aj' from deb aspectj (1.9.2-2)
  command 'ajc' from deb aspectj (1.9.2-2)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

 jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  NOTFOUND  $  npx ajx                                               14:25:58
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jessehouwing/.npm/_logs/2022-10-27T12_26_14_602Z-debug-0.log
```

It's meant to be used as a library, not as a cli.

Did you mean:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-cli

```
 jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  $  npm install ajv-cli -g                                           14:29:27

added 27 packages, and audited 28 packages in 2s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
 jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  $  ajv                                                              14:29:38
error: parameter -s is required
error: parameter -d is required


usage:
    validate:  ajv [validate] -s schema[.json] -d data[.json]
    compile:   ajv compile -s schema[.json]
    migrate:   ajv migrate -s schema[.json] -o migrated_schema.json
    test:      ajv test -s schema[.json] -d data[.json] --[in]valid

    help:      ajv help
               ajv help <command>
 jessehouwing  abrikoosje  ~  USAGE  $ 
```

Comment: _Great Mother of Conceptual Errors!_ SMDH! Thanks! 